# Optimizing Cortex-A8 color conversion using NEON

Tags: assembly, arm, neon, cpu-cache, cortex-a8

I am currently doing a color conversion routine in order to convert from YUY2 to NV12.
I have a function which is quite fast, but not as fast as I would expect, mainly due to cache misses.

```
void convert_hd(uint8_t *orig, uint8_t *result) {
uint32_t width          = 1280;
uint32_t height         = 720;
uint8_t *lineOdd        = orig;
uint8_t *lineEven       = orig + width*2;
uint8_t *resultYOdd     = result;
uint8_t *resultYEven    = result + width;
uint8_t *resultUV       = result + height*width;
uint32_t totalLoop      = height/2;

while (totalLoop-- > 0) {
  uint32_t lineLoop = 1280/32; // Bytes length: width*2, read by iter 16Bytes

  while(lineLoop-- > 0) {
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "pld [%[lineOdd]]   \n\t"
        "vld4.8   {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [%[lineOdd],:128]!   \n\t" // d0:Y d1:U0 d2:Y d3:V0
        "pld [%[lineEven]]   \n\t"
        "vld4.8   {d4, d5, d6, d7}, [%[lineOdd],:128]!   \n\t" // d4:Y d5:U1 d6:Y d7:V1
        "vld4.8   {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [%[lineEven],:128]!  \n\t" // d8:Y d9:U0' d10:Y d11:V0'
        "vld4.8   {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [%[lineEven],:128]!  \n\t" // d12:Y d13:U1' d14:Y d15:V1'
        "vhadd.u8   d1, d1, d9    \n\t" // (U0+U0') / 2
        "vhadd.u8   d3, d3, d11    \n\t" // (V0+V0') / 2
        "vhadd.u8   d5, d5, d13    \n\t" // (U1+U1') / 2
        "vhadd.u8   d7, d7, d15    \n\t" // (V1+V1') / 2
        // Save
        "vst2.8 {d0, d2}, [%[resultYOdd],:128]!           \n\t"
        "vst2.8 {d4, d6}, [%[resultYOdd],:128]!           \n\t"
        "vst2.8 {d8, d10}, [%[resultYEven],:128]!          \n\t"
        "vst2.8 {d12, d14}, [%[resultYEven],:128]!          \n\t"
        "vst2.8 {d1, d3}, [%[resultUV],:128]!   \n\t"
        "vst2.8 {d5, d7}, [%[resultUV],:128]!   \n\t"
        : [lineOdd]"+r"(lineOdd), [lineEven]"+r"(lineEven), [resultYOdd]"+r"(resultYOdd), [resultYEven]"+r"(resultYEven), [resultUV]"+r"(resultUV)
        :
        : "memory"
    );
  }
  lineOdd += width*2;
  lineEven += width*2;
  resultYOdd += width;
  resultYEven += width;
}
}
```

When I ask oprofile what is taking time, it says the following :

```
                                           :    220c:   add r2, r0, #2560   ;
                                           :    2210:   add r3, r1, #1280   ;
                                           :    2214:   add ip, r1, #921600 ;
                                           :    2218:   push    {r4, lr}
                                           :    221c:   mov r4, #360    ;
 6  0.1243    10  0.5787     4  0.4561     :    2220:   mov lr, #40 ; 0x28
 9  0.1864     5  0.2894     0       0     :    2224:   pld [r0]
45  0.9321     7  0.4051     3  0.3421     :    2228:   vld4.8  {d0-d3}, [r0 :128]!
51  1.0563     7  0.4051     1  0.1140     :    222c:   pld [r2]
 1  0.0207     1  0.0579     0       0     :    2230:   vld4.8  {d4-d7}, [r0 :128]!
1360 28.1690   770 44.5602   463 52.7936     :    2234: vld4.8  {d8-d11}, [r2 :128]!
 980 20.2983   329 19.0394   254 28.9624     :    2238: vld4.8  {d12-d15}, [r2 :128]!
                                             :    223c: vhadd.u8    d1, d1, d9
1000 20.7125   170  9.8380   104 11.8586     :    2240: vhadd.u8    d3, d3, d11
                                             :    2244: vhadd.u8    d5, d5, d13
   5  0.1036     2  0.1157     2  0.2281     :    2248: vhadd.u8    d7, d7, d15
                                             :    224c: vst2.8  {d0,d2}, [r1 :128]!
1125 23.3016   293 16.9560    15  1.7104     :    2250: vst2.8  {d4,d6}, [r1 :128]!
  34  0.7042    41  2.3727     0       0     :    2254: vst2.8  {d8,d10}, [r3 :128]!
  74  1.5327     8  0.4630     0       0     :    2258: vst2.8  {d12,d14}, [r3 :128]!
  60  1.2428    39  2.2569     6  0.6842     :    225c: vst2.8  {d1,d3}, [ip :128]!
  53  1.0978    24  1.3889    14  1.5964     :    2260: vst2.8  {d5,d7}, [ip :128]!
                                             :    2264: subs    lr, lr, #1
   0       0     0       0     1  0.1140     :    2268: bne 2224 <convert_hd+0x18>
  11  0.2278    14  0.8102    10  1.1403     :    226c: subs    r4, r4, #1
                                             :    2270: add r0, r0, #2560   ;
                                             :    2274: add r2, r2, #2560   ;
   2  0.0414     6  0.3472     0       0     :    2278: add r1, r1, #1280   ;
                                             :    227c: add r3, r3, #1280   ;
   2  0.0414     1  0.0579     0       0     :    2280: bne 2220 <convert_hd+0x14>
                                             :    2284: pop {r4, pc}
```

- the first two columns are the cycle count (absolute and relative)
- the two next ones are L1 cache miss (absolute and relative)
- the last ones are L2 cache miss (absolute and relative)

Any help would be appreciated, as this is a quite difficult task right now to find out ideas and avoid cache misses...

Thanks !

Comment: One thing that looks possible to improve is your use of cache preloading. By using PLD [R2], you're telling the system to preload memory that you're immediately going to read from. What you need to do is tell it to preload data ahead of where you're reading so that it will be ready when you need it (e.g. PLD [R2, #0x200]).

Comment: @BitBank I tried that too, but still I get a lot of cache misses on r2 (lineEven).

Comment: There's no way to avoid cache misses because the CPU is much faster than the memory. By optimizing the preload distance for both R0 and R2 you can minimize the misses. Experiment with different distances until you find the best one. This can usually speed things up by 20-25%.

Comment: Something else that will speed things up is to unroll your loop one more time. You're only using 1/2 of the NEON registers.

Comment: @BitBank on the other hand may be he has only 16D registers, as in VFPv3-D16?

Comment: You can't avoid cache misses. You can improve your cache miss ratio. Which describes what you are trying to achieve. If you are really into it, start with removing PLDs, turn loop into a single one, ensure *origin, *result is cacheline size aligned, interleave loads and stores while doing so do timing and find the sweet layout, then put some PLDs. PLDs should always be very ahead of what currently you are doing but not far away. If this wasn't a Cortex-A8 I would say drop that completely since it is hard to get right when used generically/widely on different cores.

Comment: @auselen Thanks for your tips. I wish to be able to turn the loop to a single one, but how can I achieve this ? Because, unrolling is quite heavy (loop is called 40 times right now). I can use up to 32 d registers, so I can get a loop of called 20 times... *origin and *result are aligned on 128 bits. On Cortex-A8 I see cache lines are 64 bytes [L1](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/BABFFGIG.html) and for [L2](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/BABFFGIG.html)
You think I should align origin and result on 64 bytes ?

Comment: @jmh I meant you have two while-loops, and actually it might not help but one should check disassembly for that (not that hard) - don't unroll unnecessarily. Probably aligning on 64 bytes helps but a better idea might be to take a step back and check how good is your memory bandwidth maybe by making a memcpy using vld/vst. Then compare it to your expectations. Also don't forget you are not doing a linear copy operation with your algorithm but slightly scattered.

Comment: I said is is aligned on 128bits, but it is aligned on 128 bytes. Here is the assembly code generated http://pastebin.com/gdrnZhBA

Comment: @auselen If my picture is 640x360 and not 1280x720, using the same algorithm, it takes 600µs (compared to 6000µs). This ratio (10 times faster) is critical, as the image size is only divided by 4...

Comment: @jmh can't you partition your algorithm to handle 1280x720 like 4 640x360 ?

Comment: @auselen, I am implementing it right now ;)

Comment: @auselen I tried to use the algorithm with a 1280x720 image as input, and I called the function which handles 640x360 only once. And I can see a very big difference, I should have about 600µs and I get about 1800µs.

Comment: @auselen I just tried to use a memcpy between orig and result, and it takes less than 10µs... I have a great margin of progress !

Answer (score 1):

The cache line length is fixed at eight words (32 bytes).  In addition to the `pld` you currently have, you need `pld[lineEven+cacheLine]`. The misses are `vld4.8 {d8-d11}`, which is the 2nd half of `lineEven`. `pld` will only fetch a cache line. Also, you should alter the `pld` position. Put one at the head and another before `vhadd`, maybe with next memory target.  You then have the ALU and memory units active in parallel.

Also, interleave `vst2.8 {d0, d2}` with the `vhadd`;  It looks like most data is a memory transfer.  The `vhadd` will block on data dependencies, like `d9` which you may/may not have loading from `pld`, but not scheduled well.

I am not that familiar with **NEON**, but the following is an attempt to follow what I said.

```vhdl
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "pld [%[lineOdd], #32]\n\t" // 2nd part of odd.
    "vld4.8   {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [%[lineOdd],:128]!\n\t"
    "pld [%[lineEven], #32]\n\t" // 2nd part of even.
    "vld4.8   {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [%[lineEven],:128]!\n\t"
    "vld4.8   {d4, d5, d6, d7}, [%[lineOdd],:128]!\n\t"
    "vld4.8   {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [%[lineEven],:128]!\n\t" 
    "vhadd.u8   d1, d1, d9\n\t"
    // First in memory pipe, so write early.
    "vst2.8 {d0, d2}, [%[resultYOdd],:128]!\n\t"  
    "vhadd.u8   d3, d3, d11\n\t"
    "vst2.8 {d8, d10}, [%[resultYEven],:128]!\n\t"
    "vhadd.u8   d5, d5, d13\n\t"
    "vst2.8 {d4, d6}, [%[resultYOdd],:128]!           \n\t"
    "vhadd.u8   d7, d7, d15\n\t"
    "vst2.8 {d12, d14}, [%[resultYEven],:128]!          \n\t"
    "pld [%[lineOdd]]\n\t"   // 1st part of odd.
    "vst2.8 {d1, d3}, [%[resultUV],:128]!   \n\t"
    "pld [%[lineEven]]\n\t"  // 1st part of even.
    "vst2.8 {d5, d7}, [%[resultUV],:128]!   \n\t"
    : [lineOdd]"+r"(lineOdd), [lineEven]"+r"(lineEven),
      [resultYOdd]"+r"(resultYOdd), [resultYEven]"+r"(resultYEven),
      [resultUV]"+r"(resultUV)
    :
    : "memory"
);
```

Things I may have wrong are the stride of the **NEON** operations; I have no idea how wide your registers are (64/128), so more `PLD` maybe needed, etc.  It is better to interleave the store operations with the additions.  Especially, some `dX` will be loaded before others and they will be ready to use.  Otherwise, your ALU (`vhadd`) will block waiting for the data to load.

You may also wish to *prime* the loop with `pld[lineOdd]` and `pld[lineEven]` before things begin.

Comment: The preload distance has nothing to do with the cache line length; it's about how much time the system needs to read the memory so that it's ready when your code needs it.

Comment: [`PLD` for Cortex-A8](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Cbbbdaed.html) and [`PLD` for Cortex-A5](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0434b/CHDEDHHD.html); the are both talking about caches and cache lines.  Also, the data the OP presented supports the fact that the 2nd half is missing.  See also [Linux copy template](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/lib/copy_template.S) with it's `PLD` values.

Comment: True - multiple preload instructions need to be issued to load the amount being processed. I guess I misinterpreted your answer as implying that it should be the cache line length away.

Comment: I just tried your code, @artlessnoise and the result from profiling is here :
http://pastebin.com/T79H2Sfm
As you can see, it is not very good (and in fact, timing is not good either).

Comment: @jmh Move the `vld4.8  {d4-d7}` and  `vld4.8  {d12-d15}` down towards `vhadd.u8 d5, d5, d13`; those are the cache misses and you don't need the data until then.  I didn't say my code will be better; you definitely need four `pld` and not just two or you will always have cache misses.  You can also juggle the `vst` and `vld` around and/or try relocating the `pld` instructions.

Comment: Here is the result (if I understood your demand correctly) : http://pastebin.com/6MmLrU1S

Comment: They are not **demands**, just suggestions.  It looks like things are better.  You can also simply just add `pld [%[lineOdd], #32]` and `pld [%[lineEven], #32]` at the start of your original code.  This is the one issues I suggested.  It will reduce the L2 cache misses.  It seems that last version has also reduced the L2 cache misses.  Whether the algorithm is optimal or not, I don't know.  I was addressing *to find out ideas and avoid cache misses...*.  Your code can never be better than a `memcpy()`.  Ie, your memory bandwidth of the SDRAM; this is the best you can expect.

Comment: It seems much better?  1200 cycles versus 4000 for the inner loop.  Is that correct?

Comment: If your memory copied per loop is 128 bytes and your cache is 64, then you need to change to `pld[%[lineOdd], #64]`, etc.  This depends on your cache line size and the amount of memory you copy per loop.  Although from your profile data, it seems you have 32byte cache lines.

Comment: An ARM reference on [memcpy() for the cortex-A8](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html) which limits the `PLD` to an L2 size.  I guess that an L1 miss is not so expensive.  Notice they prefetch far in advance.  I think the stride of your HD video (5*256) causes occasional L2 misses.