# ARM NEON: Tools to predict performance issues due to memory access limited bandwidth?

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, neon, cortex-a8

I am trying to optimize critical parts of a C code for image processing in ARM devices and recently discovered NEON.

Having read tips here and there, I am getting pretty nice results, but there is something that escapes me. I see that overall performance is very much dependant on memory accesses and how they are done.

Which is the simplest way (by simple I mean, if possible, not having to run the whole compiled code in an emulator or simulator, but something that can be feed of small pieces of assembly and analyze them), in order to get an idea of how memory accesses are "bottlenecking" the subroutine?

I know this can not be done exactly without running it in a specific hardware and specific conditions, but the purpose is to have a "comparison" trial-and error tool to experiment with, even if the results are only approximations.

(something similar to [this](http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php?lng=us) great tool for cycle counting)

Comment: Unfortunately, each system will have different *cycles* for memory.  In order to do a proper analysis, you would need exact timings.  For DDR SDRAM, this can be very complex as burst within a page, across a bank, read followed by write, etc have different timings.  In order to make this less hardware dependent (or even where the allocator put stuff), you need your algorithm to get the data to L2 or L1 well before use.

Comment: Thanks! I supposed so. But decided to ask since I do not need exact timings, and just wanted something to give me "hints" about if certain changes could benefit or "kill" my subroutine before testing them on ARM-NEON plattforms, but I suppose it is still too general. BTW, when you say getting the data to L2 or L1, do you mean using preloads (PLD)? If there is more, pls where can I find?

Comment: Yes, `PLD` is the normal way to do this.  See [Cortex-A8 Neon color conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604857/optimizing-cortex-a8-color-conversion-using-neon), etc.  Most **ARM** documents say that `PLD` is like a fake memory access that doesn't wait for completion.  It will just fill an **L1** and **L2** line for that address in the background as the CPU does other things.  These line sizes can be different depending on the particular chip.  There are ways to find out dynamically, but most people will hard code it for a particular system to simplify the assembler.

Comment: Some ARMs have a `PLD` as a `NOP`, like the ARM926.  So for it, a `PLD` is just instruction pollution.  An ARM reference on [`memcpy()` for the cortex-A8](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html) which limits the `PLD` to an L2 size. I guess that an L1 miss is not so expensive. Notice they prefetch far in advance.  Your algorithm will either be CPU or memory bound.  Knowing the memory bandwidth can tell you which one.  Knowing the *zero cycle* code timing can give a CPU bound.  Knowing both you should know which side to work on.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting the memcpy link! Any tips for the write part?

Comment: I don't think *writing* should cause the CPU to stall.  *write* is from the CPU to DDR.  A *read* is from DDR to CPU.  It is possible if there are many writes pending you might block.  However, your algorithm is probably memory bandwidth constrained if writes are blocking.  Nothing beats measuring real times to see.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've probably answered your own question. Memory is a system level effect and many ARM implementers (Apple, Samsung, Qualcomm, etc) implement the system differently with different results.

However, of course you can optimize things for a certain system and it will probably work well on others, so really it comes down to figuring out a way that you can quickly iterate and test/simulate system level effects.  This does get complicated so you might pay some money for system level simulators such as is included in ARM's RealView.  Or I might recommend getting some open source hardware like a Panda Board and using valgrind's cache-grind.  With linux on the panda board you can write some scripts to automate your testing.

It can be a hassle to get this going but if optimizing for ARM will be part of your professional life, then it's worth the (relatively low compared to your salary) software/hardware investment and time.

Note 1: I recommend against using PLD.  This is very system tuning dependent, and if you get it working well on one ARM implementation it may hurt you for the next generation of chip or a different implementation.  This may be a hint that trying to optimize at the system level, other than some basic data localization and ordering stuff may not be worth your efforts? (See Stephen's comment below).

Comment: Regarding PLD, it’s worth noting that most of the more modern cores have some form of “streaming prefetch”; they will recognize linear memory access and prefetch on their own without requiring explicit prefetch instructions.

Comment: Yes, I suspected something similar but prefered to ask, since I'm quite new to this world. Anyway, as I see performance differences (on a specific plattform, i.e., my mobile device) depending on how I use PLD, wanted to know if there was a magic rule for it. Another possibility (just wondering) would be to determine at real time the best PLD schema for a specific plattform to be chosen among 2 or 3, but don't know if this would make sense if the system behaviour would also change dinamically.

Comment: Yes indeed it would be interesting to determine at run-time how to best use very system specific features like PLD.  The best DSP libraries, like Intel Performance Primitives, do CPU dispatching - they detect the particular Intel CPU variant being used, and then use the best assembly for it.  Unfortunately in the ARM world, many vendors are very secretive about their implementations of the ARM ISA, so it seems difficult (to me) to engineer a solution the way Intel does.

Answer (score 2):

Memory access is one thing that simply *cannot* be modeled from "small pieces of assembly” to generate meaningful guidance.  Cache hierarchies, store buffers, load miss queues, cache policy, etc … even relatively simple processors have an enormous amount of “state” hiding underneath the LSU, and any small-scale analysis cannot accurately capture that state.  That said, there are a few basic guidelines for getting the best performance:

- maximize the ratio of "useful computation” instructions to LSU operations.
- align your memory accesses (ideally to 16B).
- if you need to pick between aligning loads or aligning stores, align your stores.
- try to write out complete cachelines when possible.
- PLD is mainly useful for non-uniform-but-somehow-still-predictable memory access patterns (these are rare).
- For NEON specifically, you should prefer to use the `vld1` and `vst1` instructions (with an alignment hint). On *most* micro-architectures, in most cases, they are the fastest way to move between NEON and memory.  Eschew `v[ld|st][3|4]` in particular; these are an attractive nuisance, slower than doing separate permutes on most micro-architectures in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I will use them and see what happens. The specific routine I'm stuck at is for image rotation. In plain C it took  about 2-3msec to rotate a 240*400 image. When I wanted to double density (480*800) I expected the time to increase by a factor of 4, but it takes more than 20msec. Then I decided to try with NEON, in some other routines (not rotation) the speed has increased a lot. But in this one is the same or even slower.

Comment: Are you rotating by 90 degrees, or doing arbitrary rotation?

Comment: Just 90 in different configurations, sometimes CCW and/or flipping. The purpose is to adapt the camera preview (after converting it to RGB) to the screen settings and do some stuff over the same preview

Comment: Have just measured it and it is about 13msec, but still too much I think

Comment: And how can I know the size of a cacheline?